# Are Samaritans viewed as adherents of Judaism?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, history, orthodox, non-rabbinic-judaism

In Judaism, particularly from an Orthodox perspective, are Samaritans seen as fellow Jews? Sometimes I see their religion referred to as 'Samaritanism', sometimes as Judaism.

Also, is it halachically appropriate for a Jew to pray in a Samaritan house of worship?

Comment: As usual, be weary of the accuracy but the old standby, Wikipedia has a lengthy entry that might answer your questions. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritans

Comment: they are like goyim see chullin 6a we pasken like Rav Ami and Rav Asi ,and see Tosfos 3b in chullin converts inspired by lions or dreams

Comment: I have a Samaritan acquaintance, and he said they are not Jews. They consider themselves Israelites, but not Jews.

Comment: @A.Concerned.Lurker Haven't read everything here, although I should. I remember researching this question awhile ago. I think we say that they are considered Jews for matters in which they agree with us (=~d'oraisas) and non-Jews in matters in which they don't. I'm sure the halachic reality is way more complicated than I have just explained, but maybe it's a start

Answer (score 5):

**Samaritans are not Jews.**

R Yosef Eisen at [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2836152/jewish/The-Samaritans-Cutheans.htm) explains why

> When the Assyrians exiled the Ten Tribes, the conquerors brought in a
>   foreign people called Cutheans to populate the vacated territory.
>   These people were idol-worshipers, and G‑d sent lions to decimate
>   them. Out of fear of the lions, the Cutheans converted to Judaism, but
>   the rabbis of the Talmud debated whether their conversion was valid or
>   not. The Cutheans’ Torah observance was spotty — extremely strong in
>   some areas, but very weak or nonexistent in others.
>
> Settling in the Samaria region of Eretz Israel, over time the Cutheans
>   became known as Samaritans. Fearing that the Jews returning from
>   Babylonian exile would reclaim their ancestral lands, the Cutheans
>   became bitter enemies of the Jewish people, even going so far as to
>   attempting to sabotage the construction of the Second Temple.
>   Disguising their evil intentions, the Cutheans offered to help build
>   the Temple. Realizing the Cutheans’ real goal, the Jews rebuffed their
>   proposed aid. Stung by this rejection, the Cutheans convinced
>   Ahasuerus that the Jews wished to foment rebellion against Persian
>   rule, so he suspended construction.
>
> On a number of occasions during the Second Temple Era, the Cutheans
>   were an anathema to the Jewish people. Finally, when the rabbis of the
>   Talmud discovered that the Cutheans were worshiping idols and not
>   keeping the commandments, the sages expelled the Cutheans from the
>   Jewish fold and declared them to be gentiles. Although most of the
>   Cutheans eventually died out, a small group exists today, living
>   around Mount Gerizim in Israel. **While they have ancient scrolls that
>   bear some resemblance to the Five Books of Moses, these descendants of
>   the ancient Cutheans have no connection to the Jewish people.**

[Ohr Somayach](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/230/Q3/) explains further

> The Samaritans were non-Jews brought to Israel by the Assyrians to
>   populate the North after the exile of the Ten Tribes. They ostensibly
>   converted to Judaism, but in reality they continued worshipping idols,
>   save for a period when they were mistakenly considered genuine
>   converts; **hence the Samaritans were not considered Jews, neither by
>   Jewish law nor by the Jewish people.**
>
> They did not accept the Oral Tradition, which forms the overwhelming
>   bulk of Jewish law. They also did not accept any books of the Bible
>   except for the Pentateuch and the book of Joshua. Today, the Samaritan
>   version of the Torah manuscript differs from ours by about 800
>   letters.
>
> The Samaritans often acted as enemies of the Jewish people. They tried
>   to destroy the Temple and to inform against the Jews to Roman
>   authorities. The parable of the "Good Samaritan" was actually an
>   anti-Semitic story intended to discredit the Jews.

For references in the gemara see e.g., [here](http://new.steinsaltz.org/daf/avodah-zarah-15a-b-kutim-samaritans/) and [there](http://new.steinsaltz.org/daf/avodah-zarah-22a-b-the-torah-of-the-samaritans/).

**As to whether you can pray in their house of worship**, you do not say if you mean it as part of an organized prayer service (very likely forbidden by all) or alone. Circumstances are important as one issue at play is *marit ayin* (giving the impression their religion is authentic Judaism). Since their religion is not *avoda zara*<sup>1</sup> it could possibly be permitted to pray there alone (see bottom of [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=2367) and bottom of [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-bo/)) but it is a *halachic* dispute and you need to [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

<sup>1</sup> To be sure, I asked [Aaron Shaffier](http://tourguideaaron.com/) (also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/530/aaron-shaffier) on MY), a religious tour guide who has been many times to Har Gerizim. He wrote that "As far as anyone can tell they are complete monotheists".

Comment: This does not quote contempory Halacha to support your notion that they ar not Jewish, a lesson in history the does not legitimise the answer so look at the other answer for those who require proof and don't want to rely on this very nice persons parole alone

Comment: "When the Assyrians exiled the Ten Tribes, the conquerors brought in a foreign people called Cutheans to populate the vacated territory. " - source?  https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4818-cuthah

Answer (score 1):

The Shomronim/Samaritans were Populating the area of Samaria in Israel by Sancherev and were orriginally from several places included Kutta hence they are referred to by there orriginal names in the Gemara Chullin 6a as the "Kuttim" See Melachim 2 17,24:

> וַיָּבֵא מֶלֶךְ אַשּׁוּר מִבָּבֶל וּמִ**כּוּתָה** וּמֵעַוָּא וּמֵחֲמָת וּסְפַרְוַיִם **וַיֹּשֶׁב בְּעָרֵי שֹׁמְרוֹן** תַּחַת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל

There is a Machlokes Rabbi Meir and Rabbanan whether Kutim were Jewish or not But even Rabbi Meir accepted in the end that since they found a graven idol of a Dove that they were not Jewish see Chullin 6b

Read this From Pirkei derabbi Eliezer Ch37  that According to Rabbanan that the Kutim were Geirei Arayot i.e they weren't genuine, the Cuttim were banned from the people of Israel in the time of Ezra, even though initially they were thought to be jewish:

וכשגלו ישראל ממקומם משומרון לבבל שלח המלך עבדיו והושיבו אותם בשומרון להעלות מס למלכות מה עשה הב"ה שלח בהם את האריות והיו הורגים בהם שלחו ואמרו למלך בבל אדוננו המלך הארץ ששלחנו עליה אינה מקבלת אותנו כי נשארנו מעט מהרבה שלח המלך וקרא לכל זקני ישראל ואמ' להם כל השנים הללו שהייתם בארצכם לא שכלה אתכם חיית השדה ועכשו אינה מקבלת אתכם אמרו לו דבר של עצה אולי ישיב אותם לארצם אמרו לו אדננו המלך הארץ ההיא אינה מקבלת גוי שאינו נמול אמ' להם תנו שנים מכם וילכו וילמדו תורה ודבר המלך אין להשיב ושלחו וקראו את ר' דוסתאי ואת ר' ינאי ומלו אותם והיו מלמדים אותם תורה שבכתב נוטריקון ובוכים והגוים האלה היו הולכים בחוקות התורה ובחוקות אלהיהם את ה' היו יראים ואלהיהן היו עובדין עלה עזרא מבבל וזרובבל בן שאלתיאל ויהושע בן יהוצדק והתחילו בונים בהיכל שנ' באדין זרובבל בן שאלתיאל וכו' ובאו עליהם השומרונים למלחמה מאה ושמונים אלף וכי שומרונים היו והלא כותיים היו אלא על שם עיר שומרון נקראו שומרונים ועוד שבקשו להרוג נחמיה שנ' לכה ונודעה יחדו ועוד שבקשו לבטל מלאכת שמים שתי שנים והיתה בטלה עד שנת היובל מה עשה עזרא וזרובבל בן שאלתיאל ויהושע בן יהוצדק קבצו כל ישראל אל היכל ה' והביאו שלש מאות כהנים ושלש מאות שופורות ושלש מאות ספרי תורות והיו תוקעים בהם והלויים משוררין ומזמרין ומנדין את הכותיים בסוד שם המפורש בכתב הנכתב על הלוחות ובחרם בית דין העליון ובחרם בית דין התחתון שלא יאכל אדם פת כותיים עד עולם מכאן אמרו כל האוכל בשר משחיטת כותי כאילו אוכל בשר חזיר ואל יתגייר אדם כותי ישראל ואין להם חלק בתחיית המתים שנ' לא לכם ולנו לא בעה"ז ולא בעה"ב ועוד שלא יהיה להם חלק ונחלה בירושלם שנ' ולכם אין חלק וצדקה וזכרון בירושלם ושלחו החרם אצל ישראל ועוד הוסיפו עליהם חרם על חרם והמלך כורש קבע עליהם חרם עולם שנ' ואלהא די שכן שמיא תמ.

The Shulchan aruch Orach Chaim 215,2 says:

> אם היה המברך אפיקורוס או כותי או תינוק, או היה גדול ושנה ממטבע הברכות, אין עונין אחריו אמן
>    I.e a Kutti is not Jewish so we Don't say "amen" to his Brochos.

The Mishna Berura  says:
?ואע"ג דבגמרא אמרינן שאף בכותי עונין אם שמע כל הברכה מפיו היינו קודם שמצאו להן דמות יונה בהר גרזים שהיו עובדין לה אבל אח"כ לא דכונתן להר גרזים
Even though the Gemora talks about Theoretical cases of Kutim this was before an idol of a dove was found on Mount Gerizim which they were worshipping but after (e.g nowadays) they are idol worshippers and not Jewish

**So we can't pray in their temples as we consider them idolitors.**

Comment: We seem to disagree on whether or not "Samaritanism" today is avoda zara. Did you see recent information that they are worshipping idols nowadays?

Comment: @mbloch We cannot discern where they are praying towards since they have an idol on mount gerizim so even if they claim they are praying to Hashem this could just be because their minhag is to do so as their ancestors were swallowed by lions but their main deity is on mount gerizim which they wont necessarily tell us as about it says in tehillim 144 "Their mouths speak falsehood"

Comment: I am asking if they still have an idol **today** and are praying towards it. Did you see this mentioned somewhere? I didn't despite looking for it

Comment: in 1933 the chafetz chaim was still around and he said this (see above) so for 2500 years nothings changed, thats good enough proof for me

Comment: With huge respect due to the CC, many things changed in Israel in the last 84 years. To be sure, I asked [Aaron Shaffier](http://tourguideaaron.com/about/), a religious tour guide who has been many times to Har Gerizim. He wrote that "As far as anyone can tell they are complete monotheists".

Comment: _even though initially they were jewish_ What does it mean to initially be Jewish? How does one stop being Jewish?

Comment: @mevaqeshthe fact that they are not Jewish and were once considdered Jewish gives legitamacy to the pirkei Drabbi eliezer that the Beis Din of Ezra removed their Jewish status, as Halacha in Shulchan Aruch says they are goyim nowadays  according to everyone and The Rabbanut have confired their non Jewish status here https://books.google.co.il/books?id=5RVACwAAQBAJ&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=rabbinate+conversion+samaritans&source=bl&ots=COtE10ohxm&sig=Gy_aW3bg4J2NKxoc0fEeWyzfuuk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2_bnGtpbYAhXDZ1AKHWbxDBoQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=rabbinate%20conversion%20samaritans&f=false

Comment: With all due respect to both you and the Chofetz Chaim, can we be sure that the Kutim and the Shomronim are the same people?

Comment: @ezra Shomron is an area of Israel that was populated by the Kutites after the Jews were exiled so shomronim and kutim are the same people one is their original name and one is there place of living post Sancherev see melachim 2 it mentions this explicitely in a Passuk

Comment: @ezra please see my edit which addresses your concern

Comment: @user15464 You are wrong. Once a Jew is always a Jew. Even if a Jew becomes a Christian, atheist, or Muslim, his status remains a Jew. The Talmud relates, "even though the people have sinned, they are still Israel." See Rabbi Maurice Mizrahi's video [here](https://youtu.be/GpbP4K0wKE0?t=448).

Answer (score -3):

They call themeselves Israelites, not Jews, though as the person said above, since the beta Israel supposedly come from the tribe of Dan and call themselves Jews, I think it should apply to Samaritans too.
Also, you need to remember that the bible is not 100% factual and documented with infallible and accurate expertise. The Kuthim convert story likely did not actually happen in real life, and historians think it went like this.

When the Assyrians came, they only took the elites from the Northern Tribes, and the everyday people who were likely the majority, mixed in with people they deported, and thus they are Israelites.
I think the Hebrew Bible documents it as if they're foreigners, because nobody from the Southern tribes went to the North at this point, and likely did not notice it at all, and when Judeans went there to check up on the place, the newly mixed people seemed like foreigners and from then on, were called Kuthim.

You can downvote me all you want like what happened to the other guy who said this, but this is actually what happened.

One of the sources.
https://blog.23andme.com/articles/samaritans-genetic-history

Comment: If you say stuff like, "the Jews aren't really Jews" , you're going to get down voted on MY. Likewise saying that the Torah is not factual. Besides that, there are no sources or support for this answer, so it would get a downvote from me even if I basically agreed.

Comment: Agree with @EthanLeonard on this. This is a SE site, not your favorite subreddit. You'll get downvoted here on a much more objective rubric.

Comment: Well, I sent a link to a source if you would like to read through it.

Answer (score -6):

**Although they are not Jews they are Israelites and we might as well call them Jews**

After the death of King Solomon, the Israelite kingdom slipt and the northern kingdom was called Israel, recalling Jacob, Israel, while the southern kingdom was called Judah, after the tribe of Judah. Thus, the term Jew is shorted for Judeans.

Similarly, the name Samaritan is named after Samaria, north of Jerusalem. They claim to be Israelites since they say they are from the Northern tribes of Israel, “The Ten Lost Tribes”. Today we might call them Jews since we refer to beta Israel (Ethiopia) as Jews, despite the fact that they are not from Judea. The idea that the Assyrians displaced all of the Jews in the Northern kingdom of Israel with Cush “Cutheans” is mistaken. The vast majority of Jews remained. Rabbi Bar-Ron explains:

> The inhabitants of Samaria were, for the most part, the remainder of
> those tribesmen who were vacated by Assyria, only subdued. Only the
> warriors, the educated elite and highly-skilled had been exiled. That
> the majority remained, for which we have the official Assyrian records
> and hints in Na"Kh (Prophets and Writings) to prove it... The
> inscriptions of Sargon II clearly show that a total of 27,280 people
> were deported. (Nimrud Prisms, COS 2.118D, pp. 295–296) Even if one
> adds several thousand who would have died in the war, it is clear that
> a healthy majority remained in the Land. Samaritan traditions do
> recall the influx of many foreigners into the land, brought in by the
> Assyrian conquerors, but their paternal genetics (overwhelmingly J1
> and J2) support Samaritan oral tradition that they accepted no men
> into their community from among those foreigners.  Only women, who
> were converted.  It is the exact same pattern as we see for Jewish
> communities throughout history.  (In fact the mtDNA of the females of
> the community is nearly identical to that of the females of the Jewish
> Iraqi community.)  Rabbi Akiva clearly suggests those conversions
> were recognized, in his words brought in the Talmud Bavli Qidushin
> 75a). Their purity as Israelites and even the purity of their path
> was not lost to the Nassi of the Sanhedrin in his day, Rabban Shim`on
> ben Gamliel, who held them to be as kosher Jews in every regard (" רבן
> שמעון בן גמליאל אומר כותי כישראל לכל דבר"
>
> - Jer. Talmud, tr. Demai 14,1).  The Mishnah ruled that the could be counted to form a "zimmun" for Birkath HaMazon (BT Berakhoth 45a).
>   The Nassi went as far as to say, “any religious duty which the
>   Samaritans preserved, they observe with far greater punctiliousness
>   than Israelites [Jews].” ( "כל מצוות שהחזיקו בהן כותים הרבה מדקדקין
>   בהן יותר מישראל" - ibid. 47b and Tosefta Pesaḥim 2,3).  In II
>   Chronicles ch. 30 we see that after the exile of the Kingdom of Israel
>   (the Ten Tribes), the king of Judah was sending messengers to the
>   Northern Tribes still in the Land (see II Chr. 30:5) to join Yehudah
>   in a great Passover celebration. Large numbers of the Israelites of
>   those regions were never exiled! That is what empires like Assyria
>   did to defeated kingdoms.  To transfer an entire population was not
>   only unnecessary overkill, it would have been prohibitively expensive.
>   On the contrary, they would effectively "decapitate" their defeated
>   peoples: taking captive their ruling class, military men and the
>   educated, leaving the simpler masses (kohanim, farmers, ranchers,
>   etc.) unable to rise and achieve independence.

When II Kings says that all the Jews left this is hyperbolic and means “many.” This is why the Samaritans call themselves Bnei Yisrael, Israelites.[1] Thus, they are monotheists and we can pray at their houses of worship.

[1] In the Bible, the Hebrews, or Israelites of the Bible are also called Bnei Yisrael.

Also, see this essay [here](https://blog.23andme.com/ancestry-reports/more-than-just-a-parable-the-genetic-history-of-the-samaritans/), which argues that Jews and Samaartians unmistakeably share the same genetic information (common ancestry).

---

PS If we can pray at a Muslim mosque (Muslims are monotheists), which is halachically acceptable even though they hate us, I find it a degradation that answers here tells us that we should not worship alongside our brothers.